# how does go read the data of tcp.conn before stream copy

Tags: go, tcpclient

```golang
func handleClient(p2, p1 net.Conn)
    streamCopy := func(dst io.Writer, src io.ReadCloser) {
    if _, err := generic.Copy(dst, src); err != nil {
            log.Println(err, "in:", p1.RemoteAddr(), "out:", fmt.Sprint(p2.RemoteAddr(), "(", p2.ID(), ")"))
    }
    p1.Close()
    p2.Close()
}
//p1 p2 they all net.conn

//here i want read p1's data do something
go streamCopy(p1, p2)
streamCopy(p2, p1)
}
```

//for generic.Copy src code:

```golang
    func Copy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) (written int64, err error) {
if wt, ok := src.(io.WriterTo); ok {
    log.Println("io.WriterTo")
    return wt.WriteTo(dst)
}
if rt, ok := dst.(io.ReaderFrom); ok {
    log.Println("io.ReaderFrom")
    return rt.ReadFrom(src)
}

buf := make([]byte, bufSize)
return io.CopyBuffer(dst, src, buf)
```

I want to do two things:

1.p1's data must be read before they are copy change.

2.then copy the stream,like reverse proxy, I try to use
buf := bytes.Buffer{}
tee := io.TeeReader(p1, buf),
I can read the data, but the stream copy fails, I hope there is a way to read the buffer without affecting p1...so i don't know

Comment: Is it your goal to read p1 to a buffer before writing that data to p2?  What is the purpose of generic.Copy?  Why not use io.Copy directly?

Comment: p1 p2 from a http get request

Comment: What is the goal of checking `WriterTo` and `ReaderFrom` when `io.CopyBuffer` (and hence, `io.Copy`) does the exact same thing?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are creating an HTTP proxy at the network connection level.  Do you want to record the contents of a data stream for access after the transaction is done, view the data stream as it's copied from one connection to the other,  capture one of the data streams before writing the data to the peer?  Which data stream to you want to capture? It will help if you show more of your proxy code.

Comment: @Seaman: that doesn't answer the question -- do you want to read and inspect the data from `src` before writing it to `dst`? That seems straightforward, what problem are you having doing that? What does "stream copy fails" mean here?

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes,I need to read the data of p1 before they copy, like uri, referer etc and do some other operations

Comment: Create a bufio.Reader on p1.  Use bufio.Reader methods to read to the end of the request header.  Write request headers to p2.  io.Copy(p2, bufioReader).